# Read an external .json file and display in html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to connect to an external .json file and display the results in html.

Here is my json

```
{
"jobid": "2018-1109",
"overview": "hello world",
"links": [
   {
     "rel": "self",
     "title": "hello world"
   }
]
}
```

I'm not sure how to bring the .json file into my html file and display the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm testing this on a local server so my connection to the file is successful. All of the references and examples that I've found haven't led me to the correct answer.

I know I can use $.getJSON(); to bring in the file, I'm just confused as to what to do with it once I have it in javascript.

Comment: _"I'm just confused as to what to do with it once I have it in javascript."_ me too, what _do_ you want to use it for once you have it?

Comment: I want to echo or append the results in my html file for display. Output would be <h1>hello world</h1>

Comment: And where lies your problem in doing that? How have you tried to add the data to the HTML? Please share a [mcve] with us showing us what your problems are

Comment: So what's the problem? Is the documentation for `getJSON` not enough to show you how to get to the data you've just fetched? Do you need to read an introductory tutorial on modifying HTML with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the jquery documentation I was able to get the data displayed:

```
$.getJSON( "displayjob.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```